# Updating theorem number in tex file

Tags: theorems, sourcecode, proofreading

I honestly do not know how to search for this feature. Recently, I had an experience with skylatex for proofreading. One of the features I really enjoyed was that once I compiled my source file, the system put a comment in front of every theorem I had. For instance, if my source file contained

```
\begin{theorem}...
```

it would return

```
%txx     <- xx is the theorem number
\begin{theorem}....
```

What is the feature called, and which system do I need to use?

Comment: So you are looking for some feature of SkyLaTeX that compiles a document and insert a comment above with number of theorem automaticly? But what is SkyLaTeX?

Comment: @Cragfelt Possibly https://www.skylatex.com (not really much informative home page).

Comment: @egreg We will stay in doubt about SkyLaTeX, then.

Comment: SkyLaTeX might have a name for the feature, but I don't know if a general name exists. Was the number just a running number, or the same number that you got in the PDF? (E.g. if theorems were numbered by section did you get for example `%t1.3` for the last theorem in section 1, and `%t2.1` for the first theorem in section 2, or did the comments say `%t3` and `%t4`?) I don't know if any editors do this, but you could probably write a script with e.g. Python to do this.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. They were the same number as in the PDF. I was suspecting that there would be some script which does the job.